# Problems with Magento API and Varnish

Tags: api, magento, magento-1.9, varnish

I have a problem with cart update by API.

I use Varnish with Phoenix.

Update cart from website frontend is working fine, but if I try to update cart from API with this code, I get an old cached version of data.

Example: If in XYZ customer's cart I have 3 products and he's adding another from web in Android app mobile which uses the API, then the cart is not updated.

The code that I use for fetching cart details is as below:

```
$quote     = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($customerId);
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
```

I think that this problem comes from the use of cookie, but I don't have an idea about how to do it. Obviously, if I disable varnish or if I refresh the cache everything works fine.

I am working on Magento 1.9.0.1, Varnish 3.0.7 and Phoenix 4.2.3

Thanks!

Comment: In which file are you using this code? Which api you are using?

Comment: Use this code in a php file that populates the cart in my android app

Answer (score 0):

In varnish you will have to clear the cache programmatically for your changes to appear on frontend. You can get the code to clear the cache from the controller action which is called when u clear the cache from backend.

Simply call this action after your API functionality is done and it will work as expected. You can also, Check if varnish clears cache based on any event that is fired. You can trigger this event after your functionality is done.

Also, I think u will have to do it only for the first item that user adds in cart. varnish cache system stops caching based on 5 dis-qualifiers - if user is logged in, if item is in wishlist, if item is added to cart, and 2 more. You can find these dis-qualifiers in its model or helper file. So when first item gets added to cart it should stop caching automatically for rest of the items.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Ok, but this means that every time a user adds an item to the cart I have to clean the cache of varnish, is not too heavy for the server?